# Mail-Merge loop and passing query parameters

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am looking to optimize and rewrite some code to loop a bunch of mail merges that run on command click.  Right now, there exists 8 individual merges that run after each other.  My problem is that I run 8 queries, which all require a start/end date to pull information from a table and feed it over to the mail merge document.  I would like to specify the parameter date, through say, inputbox and then pass it to all the merges in the loop.

```
For i = 1 To 1 'will change to 8 :)

Select Case i
 Case 1
wordDoc = pathToDocToMerge
sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM [QUERY - FIRST LETTERS]"
sqlConex = "QUERY - FIRST LETTERS"
strExport = "Normal"
fileout = desktopPath & "\ " & strmonth & " - FIRSTLETTERS.pdf"
Case 2
Case 3
Case 4
Case 5
Case 6
Case 7
Case 8
End Select


    Set objword = GetObject(wordDoc)

    objword.Application.Visible = False

    objword.MailMerge.OpenDataSource _
    Name:=pathToMDB, _
    LinkToSource:=True, _
    Connection:=sqlConex, _
    sqlstatement:=sqlStr

    objword.MailMerge.Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
    objword.MailMerge.Execute

    If printtopdf = vbYes Then

    objword.Application.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
    fileout _
    , ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=True, OptimizeFor:= _
    wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument
     objword.Application.ActiveDocument.close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges

    Else

    objword.Application.Options.PrintBackground = False
    'Print one copy of the letter
    objword.Application.ActiveDocument.PrintOut
    'Close Word and do not save the changes

    End If

    objword.Application.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    Set objword = Nothing

Next i
```

I know parameters can be passed like so:

```
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim prm As DAO.Parameter
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("qry_AMIS")

For Each prm In qdf.Parameters
    prm = Eval(prm.Name)
Next prm

Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset
```

But I am unsure how to tie this into a mail merge, seeing as the query becomes RST.  Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a quick look at the documentation for `MailMerge.OpenDataSource` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841005.aspx), I don't see why you couldn't just change your existing code...

```
sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM [QUERY - FIRST LETTERS]"
```

...to something like...

```
sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM [QUERY - FIRST LETTERS] WHERE SomeDate=#" & Format(CDate(Me.txtSpecifyDate.Value), "yyyy-mm-dd") & "#"
```

...where `Me.txtSpecifyDate` is a text box on the form you use to prompt the user to supply the date.